# System of linear equations - geometrical representation of solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So, if we're given the system:
$$x+ay=1$$
$$-ay+z=a-1$$
$$2z=a$$
where $a\neq 0$, we can write it's solutions as:
$$x=\frac{a}{2}$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{a}$$
$$z=\frac{a}{2}$$
or:
$$(x,y,z)=\bigg\{\bigg(\frac{a}{2},-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{a},\frac{a}{2}\bigg):\frac{a\in\mathbb{R}} {0}\bigg\}$$
I also wrote it as:
$$(x,y,z)=\bigg\{\bigg(0,-\frac{1}{2},0\bigg)+a\cdot\bigg(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\bigg)+\frac{1}{a}\cdot\bigg(0,1,0\bigg)\bigg \}$$
How can I understand this solution geometrically? If, instead of $\frac{1}{a}$, we had some other real number $b$, this would be a linear combination of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ shifted by vector $(0,-\frac{1}{2},0)$, which is a plane. But, in this case, we have two vectors in a linear combination, which is defined only by one real number $a$.
Is this solution even a vector space? For which parameter $a$ can we get a $0$-vector?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: $y = 1/a - 3/2$

Comment: The solution is a [curve in 3D](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28a%2F2,-1%2F2%2B1%2Fa,a%2F2%29), parametrized by $a$. $R^3$ is indeed a vector space, but this curve, which is a subset of $R^3$, is not (certainly not under the usual vector addition and scalar multiplication rules in $R^3$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an Hyperbola in the plane $x=z$ with center at $(0,-1/2,0)$.

[image]

So it is not a vector space and we cannot have the $0$ vector for any value of $a$.

Comment: May I ask what software was used to create this image? Also, how can it have a center at that point if `a` cannot be zero?

Comment: used: http://www.geogebra.org/ .

Comment: Ignore my second question. I completely misinterpreted the hyperbola word in that sentence.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. So, the solution of a non-homogeneous system of equations does not have to be a vector space, but the solution of a homogeneous system of equations has to be a vector space?

Comment: The point is not homogenity but the the fact that the dipendence of the solutions by the parameter is not linear.